# Using Javascript RegEx to find the last whitespace before inserting linebreak except for some punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's the statement I have:

```
text.replace(/(.{35})/g, "$1\n");
```

It works, it inserts a new line every 35 characters. However, I don't want a word to be cut in half. How would I find the last whitespace BEFORE that 35th character? Is it possible to do with RegEx? The block it executes on should insert up to 6 linebreaks because the overall character limit is 210 characters.

This is the current output:

```
This is an example of current output:
this is some text that has been for
matted by that statement.
```

This is what I want:

```
This is an example of current output:
this is some text that has been 
formatted by that statement.
```

It is being executed on a text field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
text.replace(/.{0,35}\b/g, "$&\n");
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mL6lT7/1)

Capturing groups are redundant here since we can access the matched text with `$&`. `\b` ensures whole word match, that we match at the word boundary. `{0,35}` is a greedy limiting quantifier (that is, it tries to match as many characters as it can), but matching will end before the 35th character if there is a word boundary earlier and 35th character is not at the boundary position.

**EDIT**:

So as not to insert the linebreak at the end of the string, and also keep a punctuation symbol in the character class on the current line, use

```
.{1,35}(?:[.,:;–—-]|\b)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/mL6lT7/2)

Comment: That looks awesome but it is inserting a linebreak before the last period even if it is not the 35th character. Could you explain why this is happening?

Example: 
    this is some text that should be \n
    formatted correctly. a max of 35 \n
    characters per line but it also \n
    should not insert unnecessary line \n
    breaks

    \n.

Comment: Perhaps, `.{1,35}(?:[.,:;–—-]|\b)` is better since it will not insert the linebreak at the end, and will also keep a punctuation symbol in the character class on the current line. Please check.